# Concurrent Ajax Calls?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to call a particular PHP script on my server several times. As each call will take some time (e.g. about .5 seconds) and each call is independent of each other, I want to call the scripts concurrently. Right now, I have something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
      url: 'main.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: { foo: 'foo' },
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
      }
    });

    $.ajax({
      url: 'main.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: { bar: 'bar' },
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
      }
    });

});
```

Instead of making these calls sequentially, I want to do them concurrently. How do I do that?

Comment: What is not concurrent with what you have shown ? There is no way to achieve two independent calls beside the one you're using.

Comment: These will be called at the same time as it is right now

Comment: ajax is asynchronous! Look at your network in dev tools , will see they are concurrent

Comment: Javascript only has one thread. As long as you don't have global ajax settings causing the requests to be synchronous, that's about as concurrent as it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what issue you are experiencing but you ***are*** making concurrent AJAX calls because jQuery defaults to `async: true`. If it defaulted to `false` then it would be called SJAX lol

One issue which you might be experiencing would be a session handling lockup.

If `main.php` is using `session_start()` then it will simply queue the bar request until foo finishes. Or you can manually call `session_write_close()` to avoid the lockup.

Answer (score 0):

Set your async = true on your AJAX calls to make them asynchronous.

```
$.ajax({
    async: "true",
      url: 'main.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: { foo: 'foo' },
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
      }
    });

    $.ajax({
    async: "true",
      url: 'main.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: { bar: 'bar' },
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax requests are asynchronous by nature. Based on your example, each of the calls will be dispatched **without waiting for the server's response**

Comment: That cannot be assumed. We would need to see the PHP code.

Comment: How will the PHP backend affect the client from sending multiple requests?

Comment: It could have a ripple effect and cause the client to reach its [concurrent connections limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser).